# vim map command ipython

Tags: vim, ipython

I'm trying to map a function which launch ipython qtconsole and next IPython from https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython.

What I did is:

```
map <key> :!ipython qtconsole&:IPython<CR>
```

When I press `<key>` on vim, it works well but messages from ipython console are displayed on vim editor so that I can't see my code.

So I tried :

```
nnoremap <silent> <key> :!ipython qtconsole&:IPython<CR>
```

But nothing changed.

Here are the displayed messages from ipython:

```
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing kernel-4812.json
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "%%!" under id 54 
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "%%capture" under id 56 
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "%%timeit" under id 57 
...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally comed up with something which works. For those who are interested in launching vim-ipython by pressing on key here is way to do that.
So in .vimrc I added the following functions:

```
function! ViPy()
    call system('ipython qtconsole &>/dev/null &')
    :sleep 500m "400m not enough so ...
    :py km_from_string("*") "same as :IPython
endfunction
```

Here is the key mapped:

```
map <F12> :call ViPy()<CR>
```

May be there is a better way to do that. Thank's to post it.

Answer (score 1):

You may silence ipython by either using `&>/dev/null` (before `&`) or using `system()` in place of a bang: `:call system('ipython qtconsole&')|IPython`.

I guess you will need `sleep` command before `:IPython` for ipython to have a chance to start though.

You have another issue here: `:!ipython qtconsole&:IPython` launches ipython with `qtconsole` argument and tries to run command `:IPython` in a separate thread *in a shell*. Obviously shell does not know anything about vim commands. Replace `&` with `&<CR>`.

Comment: Thank you for help.

**First paragraph: redirecton to null is a good idea. The command with system does not work because it sais IPython command inconnue. It is saw as a shell cmd.

**Second paragraph: I don"t think I need a delay because as I said above, It works well, I can compile but a startup of ipython qtconsole messages comes into the display (some kind of display bug, refresh).


**Three paragraph: I don't think because it works: links between vim and ipython is done. But if I add <CR>, It does in a separate thread so this issue appears

Comment: In fact when I add redirection to null, it seems that it does not take account :IPython so an error occured.

Comment: I take my word about second paragraph. I need a delay and my first command does not work it seems.

Comment: @Katsu 1. `call system('ipython qtconsole&')` works for me. Launched shell is useless regardless of what I use to launch it, but it is probably configuration bug. 3. `!...&:IPython` is just as good as `!...&xxx-unknown-command`, though message will be different (`zsh: command not found: :IPython` will change to `zsh: command not found: xxx-unknown-command`). Launching ipython in background is done with `&`; it does not matter what is to the right of `&`. Neither vim nor shell uses threads.

Comment: Ok, but it's weird that I can't do something whit that. I just have to translate into .vimrc the following commannd on vim command:1. :!ipython qtconsole $>/dev/null& 2.:Ipython. Maybe I have to create a function in .vimrc which group both command and maybe a sleep command.

Comment: +1 For &>/dev/null which partially answer the issue.